# access a specific position and get its values

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 cards and I want to put the respective title, image, etc. on each card.

How can I access each position of my object and set the values ​​on the card.

I was trying to compare the id but it won't always be the same id. So how could I achieve this, I appreciate your help.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
            <h3 id="title">Card 1</h3>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
            <h3>Card 2</h3>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
            <h3>Card 3</h3>
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    const jsonArr = '[{"product_id": 1,"product_name": "Product 1","product_image": "product1.jpg","product_price": 19.99},{"product_id": 2,"product_name": "Product 2","product_image": "product2.jpg","product_price": 24.99},{"product_id": 3,"product_name": "Product 3","product_image": "product3.jpg","product_price": 29.99}]';
    const data = JSON.parse(jsonArr);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].product_id === 1) {
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = data[i].product_name;
        }
    }

    console.log(data);

</script>
```

Comment: What is `1` supposed to represent here? I would retrieve your card elements first, then populate with the corresponding object in your `data` array

Answer (score 0):

You got the gist of it right, however, you have no way of targeting the other card, once you've dealt with the first one.

One way you could achieve this is to use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), which will return an array of html elements, containing each element with the given class:

```js
const cardElements = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
```

Now, with that in hand, you can use your loop and target the "cardElement" at the index `i`, using the `cardElements` variable we've just created and the `item`function.

```
const cardElements = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const currentCardElement = cardElements.item(i);

    /** code that define the title and all... **/
}
```

Now, to target element that are "inside" the `currentCardElement`, you can use
the `getElementsByClassName` function to target sub nodes of the card element.

When calling this function on an HTMLElement, the function will only return the matching HTMLElements in the subtree of the parent HTMLElement, the one we've called the function on.

Which mean, even if we've got more than one card with a `<h3 class="title">`, only the `h3` under the `currentCardElement` will be returned.

It might be useful to set a different class to each div that will contain data, in order to have only one element per call. For exemple:

```html
 <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
            <h3 class="title">Card 2</h3>
            <p class="image">Some text</p>
            <p class="price">Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
const cardElements = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const currentCardElement = cardElements.item(i);

    const cardTitle = currentCardElement.getElementsByClassName("title").item(0);
    cardTitle.innerHTML = data[i].product_name

    /** We do the same for the image and price using the correct class name */ 
}
```

Now, you should have populated each card with their corresponding product, from your `data` array.

Below, you will find a complete example.

```js
const jsonArr = '[{"product_id": 1,"product_name": "Product 1","product_image": "product1.jpg","product_price": 19.99},{"product_id": 2,"product_name": "Product 2","product_image": "product2.jpg","product_price": 24.99},{"product_id": 3,"product_name": "Product 3","product_image": "product3.jpg","product_price": 29.99}]';
    const data = JSON.parse(jsonArr);

const cardElements = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const currentCardElement = cardElements.item(i);

    const cardTitle = currentCardElement.getElementsByClassName("title").item(0);
    cardTitle.innerHTML = data[i].product_name;

    const cardImage = currentCardElement.getElementsByClassName("image").item(0);
    cardImage.innerHTML = data[i].product_image;
    
    const cardPrice = currentCardElement.getElementsByClassName("price").item(0);
    cardPrice.innerHTML = data[i].product_price;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
            <h3 class="title">Card 1</h3>
            <p class="image">Some text</p>
            <p class="price">Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
            <h3 class="title">Card 2</h3>
            <p class="image">Some text</p>
            <p class="price">Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
            <h3 class="title">Card 3</h3>
            <p class="image">Some text</p>
            <p class="price">Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. You should consider using the [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) functions which are easier to use since they are targeting elements using css selector.

Comment: Thanks for the help, if in "product_image" I have the url of my image, how could I show it on the card, so that the link is not shown as text but as an image. Thank you

Comment: @CocL You could add an  `image` tag, and change it's `src` attribute to the given image url.